# How to solve $y(x)^{y'(x)} = |x|^{|x|}$ for $y(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, lambert-w

To practice ordinary differential calculus, I set myself a few problems to solve.
One of those problems is "Solve $y(x)^{y'(x)} = |x|^{|x|}$ for $y(x)$!" with $x \in \mathbb{R} \backslash \left\{ 0 \right\}$ and $y(x) \in \mathbb{C} \backslash \left\{ 0 \right\}$.

So I started:
$$
\begin{align*}
y(x)^{y'(x)} &= |x|^{|x|} \quad\mid\quad \ln\left( ~~ \right)\\
\ln\left( y(x)^{y'(x)} \right) &= \ln\left( |x|^{|x|} \right)\\
y'(x) \cdot \ln\left( y(x) \right) &= |x| \cdot \ln\left( |x| \right) \quad\mid\quad \int ~\operatorname{d}x\\
\int y'(x) \cdot \ln\left( y(x) \right) ~\operatorname{d}x &= \int |x| \cdot \ln\left( |x| \right) ~\operatorname{d}x + c_{1}\\
-y(x) + \ln\left( y(x)^{y(x)} \right) &= \int |x| \cdot \ln\left( |x| \right) ~\operatorname{d}x + c_{1}\\
\end{align*}
$$

Since the equation reminds me of power towers, I tried to solve the equation with the lambert W-function:
$$
\begin{align*}
-y(x) + \ln\left( y(x)^{y(x)} \right) &= \int |x| \cdot \ln\left( |x| \right) ~\operatorname{d}x + c_{1}\\
-y(x) + \ln\left( y(x) \right) \cdot y(x) &= \int |x| \cdot \ln\left( |x| \right) ~\operatorname{d}x + c_{1}\\
-y(x) + \ln\left( y(x) \right) \cdot e^{\ln(y(x))} &= \int |x| \cdot \ln\left( |x| \right) ~\operatorname{d}x + c_{1}\\
\end{align*}
$$

Now comes the problem: I don't know how to continue.
Is there a nice way to continue?

[Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=y%28x%29%5E%28y%27%28x%29%29%3D%7Cx%7C%5E%7Cx%7C) tells me that there is solution to this formula via using the lambert W-function: $$y(x) = \frac{\int |x| \cdot \ln\left( |x| \right) ~\operatorname{d}x + c_{1}}{\operatorname{W}\left( \frac{\int |x| \cdot \ln\left( |x| \right) ~\operatorname{d}x + c_{1}}{e} \right)} \text{ or } y(x) = \frac{\int^{x}_{1} |\xi| \cdot \ln\left( |\xi| \right) ~\operatorname{d}\xi + c_{1}}{\operatorname{W}\left( \frac{\int^{x}_{1} |\xi| \cdot \ln\left( |\xi| \right) ~\operatorname{d}\xi + c_{1}}{e} \right)}$$

Just how?

Comment: Try $|x|=x>0$ and find $\int \ln(x)xdx$

Comment: @TymaGaidash How would that help solving for $y(x)$? I'm not trying to solve $\int |x| \cdot \ln\left( |x| \right) ~\operatorname{d}x$... I'm trying to find all possible $y(x)$ with $x, ~y(x) \in \mathbb{R} \backslash \left\{ 0 \right\}$ but doing $|x| = x > 0$ wouldn't help here, or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Maybe you want to restrict $y(x)>0$ instead of $\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$. Because $y(x)$ is used as an exponential base raised to who knows what kind of irrational power.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
-y(x) + \ln\left( y(x) \right)  y(x)&=E \\
 y(\ln y -1)&=E\\
y(\ln y -\ln e)&=E\\
y(\ln (y/e)=e\dfrac y e \ln \dfrac ye&=E\\
e^{\ln \dfrac y e} \ln \dfrac ye&=\dfrac E e\\
\end{align}
$$
Take the Lambert function on both sides:
$$\ln \dfrac y e=W \left (\dfrac E e\right)$$
$$y =ee^{W \left (\dfrac E e\right)}$$
and use $e^{W(y)}=\dfrac y {W(y)}$:
$$y(x) =\dfrac E {W \left (\dfrac E e\right)}$$
Where $E= \int_1^x t \ln t dt+C$.

Comment: Oh... it was easier than I thought. :') 
Thank you, hat was helpful!^^

Comment: You're welcome @KevinDietrich

Comment: Of course $\int_1^x t \ln t dt$ can be evaluated using integration by parts.

Comment: @GEdgar you're perfectly right.